# Large spaces between a bullet and the text

Tags: microsoft-word

I am wondering why everytime I try to add a bullet into a MS word document it creates a large space after it, before the text starts

It would look similar to this:

```
-                              text starts here
```

I cannot figure out how to get rid of this giant space!

Comment: Does this happen in all documents you create, or only a specific one?  Also it would be be helpful if you included in your question what version of Word you are using so answers provided can be tailored to the different menus associated with different versions of Word.

Answer (score 5):

Check the ruler along the top. I am guessing that your ruler looks something like this:

[image]

So if you drag the two sliders at the top together and adjust them to your preference then the bulleted list should be as you expect:

[image]

Comment: If the ruler is not displaying, the ruler show/hide button can be found at the top of the scroll bar on the right-hand side of the document